# Repeating a function in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, repeat

I've made this shake function to try add a shake effect to my menu title in my game. Thought I feel like this is a really long way of doing it! Is there any shorter/neater way of doing a repeat action like this?

Also is it possible to make this repeat forever?

```
func shakeMenu(){

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute:
        {

    let moveNodeRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)
    let moveNodeLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)
    let moveNodeRight1 = SKAction.moveBy(x: 7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)
    let moveNodeLeft1 = SKAction.moveBy(x: -7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)
    let moveNodeRight2 = SKAction.moveBy(x: 7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)
    let moveNodeLeft2 = SKAction.moveBy(x: -7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)
    let moveNodeRight3 = SKAction.moveBy(x: 7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)
    let moveNodeLeft3 = SKAction.moveBy(x: -7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)
    let moveNodeRight4 = SKAction.moveBy(x: 7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)


    self.shake = SKAction.sequence([moveNodeRight, moveNodeLeft, moveNodeRight1, moveNodeLeft1, moveNodeRight2, moveNodeLeft2, moveNodeLeft3, moveNodeRight3, moveNodeRight4])
    self.menu.run(self.shake)

    })
}





func shakeMenu(){

    let moveRight: SKAction = .moveBy(x: 7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)
    let sequence: SKAction = .sequence([moveRight, moveRight.reversed()]
    self.menu.run(.repeat(sequence), count: 4)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't use Grand Central Dispatch with SpriteKit

Here's the code

```
func shakeMenu() {
    let moveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)
    let moveRightLeft = SKAction.sequence([moveRight, moveRight.reversed()])
    let repeatMoveRightLeft = SKAction.repeat(moveRightLeft, count: 4)
    let waitAndMove = SKAction.sequence([.wait(forDuration: 2), repeatMoveRightLeft])
    self.menu.run(waitAndMove)
}
```

Comment: ah...I forgot about `reversed()`, clever :)

Comment: Hey! this doesn't seem to work for me. Is it correct that I would have this within my 

       function shakeMenu(){

and then call on the function where I need it?

Comment: I have added what i put in my code down the bottom of my original question^^ when I add it I'm getting errors asking for separator, and variable used within its own value.

Comment: You should not use GCD with SpriteKit. In my updated answer I show you how you can add a `wait` action.

Comment: Hi, that new one doesn't shake at all for me :O Sorry, I'm pretty new to coding! it says initialization of mutable .... etc  on the 4th line

Comment: Of course you need to run the action: `self.menu.run(waitAndMove)`

Comment: Haha sorry, Thanks a lot. I hope 1 day I can code like you!

Comment: Just realised it actually doesn't repeat for me haha

Answer (score 3):

How about `SKAction.repeatForever` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417676-repeatforever)

That way you could write:

```
let moveNodeRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)
let moveNodeLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -7.0, y: 0.0, duration: 0.05)
let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveNodeRight, moveNodeLeft])
let moveForever = SKAction.repeatForever(moveSequence)

self.menu.run(moveForever)
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Im getting value of gameScene type has no member moveForever?

Comment: Hi, Ive added this answer as correct but have just realised I still want to have the 2 second gap between each shake! Is there a way I can add that with this code?

Comment: I originally tried to have 8 movements then a 2 second pause then repeat